# when executing the command - docker exec <odoo-container> odoo scaffold <project1> /mnt/extra-addons >>>PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, odoo, scaffold

when executing the command -  docker exec  odoo scaffold  /mnt/extra-addons >>>PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied : '/mnt/extra-addons/device'
I've already tried
-sudo chmod 777 /mnt

it was supposed to be a project from scratch

Comment: Try  `-R` option to grant permission recursively like:`chmod -R /mnt`

Answer (score 0):

It works with root, like this:

```
docker exec -it --user root --name <your_container_name> /usr/bin/odoo scaffold whatever /mnt/extra-addons
```

I took this solution from [here.](https://github.com/odoo/docker/issues/159#issuecomment-412097567)